# GeoServer WFS 2.0 GetFeature query with wildcard for typeNames/featureTypes

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

Just looking through [GeoServer docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) trying to find a way to construct a WFS 2.0 query to get all features within a BBOX - regardless of feature type.

The service I'm consuming will be changing over time, so I'd prefer to use a wildcard type argument to cover all feature types in the request rather than hard-code them..

Hopefully without having to query the service prior just to determine the feature type params.

Have tried the usual syntax, e.g. `typeName=*` but no good.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Such use is not supported in WFS http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=39967. You must do GetCapabities request first and find feature types from the response.

Comment: Not the answer I had hoped for; but an answer none the less..

Comment: @user30184 Why don't you post your comment as an answer, as it seems to be the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you can't make a WFS GetFeature request with a wild card as the typename parameter value (like `TYPEname=*&`).  The GetFeature request requires a typename to be specified which must be the name of a FeatureType listed in the GetCapabilities response.